# Como armazenar um valor de um SELECT numa variável em MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

É algo bem simples mas que não encontro a informação que quero, gente!

Eu vi uma vez como fazer isso mas foi bem raso, mas vou explicar o que quero:

Tenho uma variável e quero que ela receba o valor de uma determinada coluna que virá com um `select`...

```
set @CPF = blablabla;
select * from userdocuments where Description = @CPF;
set @userID = Aqui eu quero armazenar o valor da coluna User_id que virá com o select acima;
```

Como faço para fazer essa variável `@userID` receber o valor da coluna?

Answer (score 2):

***Na*** [sql](/questions/tagged/sql):

```
select @userID := User_id from userdocuments where Description = @CPF;
```

***ou***

```
select User_id into @userID from userdocuments where Description = @CPF;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assim

```
set @userID = (select User_id from userdocuments where Description = @CPF)
```